# A member of a discriminated union has a nondiscriminant template literal type. Why does creating a value of it cause an error?

Tags: typescript, typescript-template-literals

[You can try my code in a typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQTgG8BYAKDjgBtMAjYKgLjgGcYpkBzAbnMoGtkAE2YAifKN5kAvuXKhIsRCjRZccAELE+lanQbMABhswAvOABIiSAK4BbelGmGpuuIKQi4ojZPKyycgB6IOU4TCQIGAALNDh0BCpgADpU8hgATzA8AGUbWgBVJAQIJDgAXgI4AB9NKWxStjhsKGBMVAB5WgArCrgACgBKZjzC4tKAbQBdCoA+bQpmxvgQPvYbYFclpCakAEY+gGYthp34JAAmPoBWE+W4VpYbKhgR-KKSpGm+iZ1KIj09CY3gAYhAIKIADTuYRiCRwaSQv7EQEGbwmKBQmGeOGiBFIxb-ZGUGhAowmcxWVYAfjg+zgzEuzgJbgEsPRUORiJ0Uy2rRgNigZUezxgUmkUiAA):

```
export interface A {
  label: string;
  kind: "A";
}

export interface B {
    label: `Baz ${number}`;
    kind: "B";
}

// in another file...
type SubUnion = A | B;
const createObj = (): SubUnion[] => {
  const x = true;
  const n1 = 3;
  const n2 = 5;
  const result: SubUnion[] = [
    { label: "Foo", kind: "A" },
    { label: "Bar", kind: "A" },
    {
/*
Type '{ label: string; kind: "B"; }' is not assignable to type 'SubUnion'.
  Types of property 'kind' are incompatible.
    Type '"B"' is not assignable to type '"A"'.(2322)
*/
      label: `Baz ${x ? n1 : n2}`,
      kind: "B",
    },
  ];
  return result;
};
```

I don't understand the last two lines of that error message. Why is it saying `Type '"B"' is not assignable to type '"A"'`?

Fortunately, I think I understand the first line: it's saying that `` label: `Baz ${x ? n1 : n2}`, `` is a `string` type, but `B` needs a `Baz ${number}` type. I've found ways to fix this, but I'm not sure if any are "the right way" to do it:

1. ```
   const result: SubUnion[] = [
     { label: "Foo", kind: "A" },
     { label: "Bar", kind: "A" },
     {
       label: `Baz ${x ? n1 : n2}`,
       kind: "B",
     },
   ] as const;
   ```
2. ```
   {
     label: `Baz ${x ? n1 : n2}`,
     kind: "B",
   } satisfies B,
   ```
3. ```
   {
     label: `Baz ${x ? n1 : n2}`,
     kind: "B",
   } as const,
   ```
4. ```
   {
     label: `Baz ${x ? n1 : n2}` satisfies `Baz ${number}`,
     kind: "B",
   },
   ```
5. ```
   {
     label: `Baz ${x ? n1 : n2}` as const,
     kind: "B",
   },
   ```

I can say with some confidence that `as const` is not the best way to do this: it lets you use literals that don't match the type on the left-hand side of the assignment. I don't know if that means `satisfies` is the right way to do this, but it does seem better.

In summary: Why is this error message so confusing and is there a better way to fix the error?

Comment: Interesting meta-note: the preview of this list renders correctly. I'm not sure why it's one line once I submit it. This might be a StackOverflow bug.

Comment: This seems like a bug so I created this report: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398321/post-formatting-is-not-accurate-for-numbered-lists-of-code-blocks

Comment: • What's the point of `C` and `DUnion` in this code? Seems extraneous here. Could you remove it? • "I can say with some confidence that `as const` is not the best way to do this: it lets you use literals that don't match the type on the left-hand side of the assignment." I don't understand this, what does that mean? Can you demonstrate it? Because I would say `as const` on the template literal is a perfectly reasonable approach (your #5).  continued...

Comment: ...see prev comment. • You've run into [ms/TS#57231](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57231) and for now the workaround is to put the actual discriminant *first* in the object, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mbrrPm). • The error is happening because it discriminated to the wrong member of the union, matching on `string`, which means it expects `kind` to be `"A"`, which it isn't. Seems like a straightforward error in light of ms/TS#57231.  Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: `What's the point of C and DUnion in this code?` I don't know if there is a point but I wasn't understanding much of what was going on when I created this example: I didn't have a clue to what was relevant. `...your #5...` I can't remember how I did it, but I was able to change one of the `as const` examples to be an invalid type and the compiler didn't warn me; it did when I used `satisfies`. At least that's how I remember it. Maybe ts server needed a restart at the time.

Comment: Since you can remove the `C` and `DUnion` definitions without affecting things, they're not relevant; would it be okay if I [edit] to remove them?  And... how would you like to proceed, given the contents of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78125001/a-member-of-a-discriminated-union-has-a-nondiscriminant-template-literal-type-w?noredirect=1#comment137732386_78125001) comment?

Comment: @jcalz I tried to edit it so you don't have to. If you feel like the best fix to this is to use the workaround of that bug, I think that would be a good answer. I'm not sure if I'm fully understanding the situation, so if there is a better way to resolve this error, I would want that as an answer instead.